# Unable to read files located on Unix file system with Spark using wholeTextFiles method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filesystems

I'm facing a problem concerning the reading of files deposited on a linux file system:

```
/app/dev/spark/test1.json
/app/dev/spark/test2.json
```

I'm trying to read these files using the `wholeTextFiles` method by declaration of the `SparkContext`:

```
object HdfsHelper extends App {

  val path: String = ...

  val ss: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
  val sc: SparkContext = ss.sparkContext

  val files = sc.wholeTextFiles(path).collect()

}
```

I tested several syntaxes concerning the `path` variable including the following:

```
file:////app/dev/spark 
file:///app/dev/spark
file://app/dev/spark
file:/app/dev/spark
/app/dev/spark
```

But none of them work and my program always ends with the error message:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/dev/spark/test1.json does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:539)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas ?
(I'm using the 2.4.0 Spark version.)

Comment: Is this on your laptop or on a distributed cluster? If a cluster, the files would have to be on *all* the nodes.

Comment: The program is launched in client mode, the driver runs on a given virtual machine and the executors run on a Hadoop cluster. And the files are dropped on the virtual machine (driver).

Comment: Yep, then that's your problem then.  Solution is to move the files to a common location, like HDFS.  You can do a `hadoop dfs -put` to push the files to HDFS (even in a temp location).  Then read from there instead.  All the nodes will have access to the data.